# How to set an unspecified value to Meta class (How to create a template table class) django_tables2

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I have more than 30 tables, so I don`t want to write the same code for all of them. Even its copypaste.
All my tables should look like this one:

```
class MyTable(tables.Table):
    edit_link = tables.columns.Column(viewname='edit_table_field',
        kwargs={'table_name': 'MyModel', 'pk': A('pk')}, text='edit)
    ...
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        ...
```

I want to make a tamplate from this class which will take the name of the model (**MyModel**) as an argument and create the same tablestables for each of them in one class. I don't know how to pass a value from a class to a metaclass.

Also, maybe someone know any frameworks for python that implements the mapping and CRUD methods for my tables like it`s in Vaadin (Java)?

Answer (score 0):

Since python is a highly dynamic language, you can achieve this in multiple ways. One that comes to mind (you can declare classes inside the function and also pass / return them as regular objects):

```
def get_table(model_cls):

    class ModelTable(tables.Table):
        edit_link = tables.columns.Column(
            viewname='edit_table_field',
            kwargs={'table_name': model_cls.__name__, 'pk': A('pk')}, 
            text='edit'
        )
        ...
        class Meta:
            model = model_cls
            ...

    return ModelTable


tables = [
    get_table(model)
    for model in (Brand, Product, Category)  # Your models here
]
```

You can extend this to generate complete views as well.

Comment: yeah, u right, but i dont think that this is the best way. thanks

Comment: what's your criteria for the "best"? it's concise, uses no "clever" tricks except the somewhat unusual python dynamic abilities (which however even not a pythonista should be able to understand), and achieves the goal